# How do I remove a rar file that has stuck on the applications/places toolbar?

Tags: removing

I was moving a rar file to another place when it stuck on the bottom toolbar, see screenshot below.

[image]

Right click only shows 'launch' and 'properties' options, No delete option is available.

Running ubuntu 12.04, 64 bit.

Comment: just try to move the file through terminal.

Comment: Bottom toolbar? What desktop environment are you using?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/1ZlqBWA.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hold the left alt key and right click the icon on the panel. You should see "remove from panel".

Comment: Thanx a lot..this is very kind from you. It worked

Comment: No problem. I'm so new to this I was glad I could actually help someon!